# Node.js npm install validator

Tags: node.js, npm, validation

I have to install the [validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) package for node.js

That's what I did

```
npm install validator
```

That's the output

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/validator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/validator
npm WARN package.json policyfile@0.0.4 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field
```

Any idea what to do here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignore those. They are benign warnings and don't pertain to you as a user of the validator module. The author of the validator module could fix them by correcting it's `package.json` file. Not sure why NPM prints these here as they are mostly a nuisance to npm users and they are really messages for package authors.

Comment: I think there really is no why, except for simply long-outstanding maintenance. I posted an issue about it here: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3490